# Angular - How to share data b/w an Eagerly loaded and a Lazy loaded modules?

Tags: angular

**How to share data between an Eagerly loaded and a Lazy loaded modules in Angular**

Comment: Do you have an example where this doesn't work? What kind of data exactly?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't posted with an example, but I just need a basic understanding of how the data is shared from eagerly to lazy loaded and vic-versa.

Comment: In general there's no difference between sharing data between lazy/eagerly loaded modules and between eager/eager or lazy/lazy. I'm not sure I understand your issue, that's why I asked for an example or a specific case where you have an issue

Answer (score 1):

To share data use service and inject this service in root level. You can inject service by injector root in 2 way

1. in service class with option in decorator @Injectable
2. in providers option in @NgModule

Example 1

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyDataService
...
```

Example 2 (app.module.ts)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [MyDataService],
```

Important don't declare service in provider of lazy loaded module otherwise the service will be injected by lazy loaded module injector and not by root injector.

Here a demo app https://github.com/pix303/ng-shared-service-module